# Entity Framework MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been looking through questions on here but have yet to come across anything that deals with my problem, apologies if this is a duplicate and I've missed something.

I have an ASP.Net MVC project with Entity Framework Code First.
In my Dbcontext I have;

```
public Context() : base("DatabaseName")
{
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());
}
```

In my web config I have;

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DatabaseName" connectionString="connsection string is here"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

When my application is deployed, I get the error

> 'CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.' as soon as
>   it tries to access the Context for the first time.

What I don't understand is how to stop it trying to create a database and just use the connection string that I have given it. The database already exists (It's on shared hosting so I don't have much control over it) and I know the connection string is correct as I have Hangfire installed in the same application, using the same connection string and it has successfully created the tables but for some reason EF doesn't create the tables in the database and instead tries to create one, which it cannot do.

Entity Framework is installed in the same project as the config file, in fact, it's a single project application.

I've tried creating another database and adding a second connection string in case Hangfire was preventing EF from using it but had the same issue. I've also tried putting the full connection string directly into `:base("")` on the context, but it has no effect.

Comment: are you trying to access local db or sql server db?

Comment: it's a SQL server db on a separate machine to the host

Comment: In my particular case the "Initial Catalog" was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

try getting `connectionString` by name

```
public Context()
            :base("name=DbConnection")
        {

        }
```

in `Web.config` file add

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=serveraddress;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=usename;Password=pass;Initial Catalog=databasename" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```